# What's this setting of MATLAB for(which is causing lots of troubles for lots of people)?

Tags: matlab, path

This setting in `PATH`:

```
D:\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32
```

Here is a fresh bad affect by this setting for me:

[How does PATH environment affect my running executable from using msvcr90 to msvcr80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712913/why-does-this-program-require-msvcr80-dll-and-whats-the-best-solution-for-this-k)

And here's an issue reported by another guy:

http://groups.google.com/group/ggobi/browse_thread/thread/dacea0fa93dcaf75

What's that setting for and why it's causing so many problems?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are talking about the `PATH` system environment variable or the `MATLABPATH` environment variable.  If you mean the system environment variable, Andrew's answer seems to answer the question.  Otherwise, here's some information about the MATLAB variable, in case you meant that:

The `MATLABPATH` variable in MATLAB tells MATLAB where to look for functions.  It's analogous to the `PATH` system environment variable in both Windows and *nix systems (which is what Andrew was describing), but is only for the MATLAB environment.

For example, if you had a script called `myScript.m` stored in the `C:\Users\me\Documents\MATLAB\` directory that defines the function `myScript`, you would be able to use your myScript function regardless of what directory you are currently working in in MATLAB.

You may modify your `MATLABPATH` by using the `path`, `addpath`, `genpath`, and other such functions.

Comment: It's the `PATH` system environment variable, but there are two settings for MATLAB in `PATH`, one is `D:\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32`, the other `D:\MATLAB\R2007b\bin`, obviously the one in my post is not for calling MATLAB from command line.